# What is Straishuya karma and how to perform it?

Tags: rituals

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26451/does-the-pumsavana-seemanta-ritual-pray-for-a-male-child/26467#26467) says that Pumsavana Karma is a ritual conducted for getting a male child. Somewhere I heard that similar to this ritual, there is also a ritual called Straishuya Karma which can be conducted for getting a female child. So, my questions are:

- What is Straishuya Karma?
- Which scripture mentions this ritual?
- How to perform this ritual?